# How to set height and width of a UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` with an image and a large button.

The problem is that the default `UIAlertView` is a very small size. It's image cannot be seen properly.

So, I want to increase the height and width of the `UIAlertView`. In other words, I want to create a custom `UIAlertView`. What would be the way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just make the alert view eat a lot to increase the weight? ;)

Comment: The easey way: Append / prepend extra line breaks (\n) to your message body

Comment: @basvk- thaks for replay. but it only increases the height of the alertview , not the width. and the main thing is that i want to show the image instead of the message.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3975400/845115

Comment: yeah, setting the frame does increase alertview but it's background image doesn't stretch properly - if you make it big enough (i was doing it on iPad) it really looks like it had eaten too many french fries in it's short digital life :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem in changing size of uialertview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975347/problem-in-changing-size-of-uialertview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sending you my code, I am showing a TableView in AlertView, perhaps it will help you.

in header file paste this code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface aaViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    UITextField *textfield;
    UITableView *tableView1;

    NSMutableArray *_data;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *_data;

- (void) showAlertView;
- (void) doAlertViewWithTextView;
- (void) doAlertViewWithTableView;
@end
```

and in your imlpementation(.m) file paste this code.

```
#import "aaViewController.h"

@implementation aaViewController

@synthesize _data;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self._data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Najeeb", @"Furqan", @"Khalid", nil];
    [self doAlertViewWithTableView];
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) doAlertViewWithTextView {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 550)];

    alert.title = @"Textview";
    alert.message = @"I am doing cool stuff\n\n\n";
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 90, 260, 200)];
    textView.text = @"This is what i am trying to add in alertView.\nHappy New Year Farmers! The new Winter Fantasy Limited Edition Items have arrived! Enchant your orchard with a Icy Peach Tree, and be the first farmer among your friends to have the Frosty Fairy Horse. Don't forget that the Mystery Game has been refreshed with a new Winter Fantasy Animal theme! ";
    textView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;

    [alert addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void) doAlertViewWithTableView {

    NSLog(@"Now play with TableView \n%@", self._data);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Table View" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    tableView1 = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 264, 200) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
    tableView1.dataSource = self;
    tableView1.delegate = self;
    [alert addSubview:tableView1];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

//#define kTag_EnterNameAlert  1
//#define kTag_NameEmtryField  100
- (void) showAlertView {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!"
                                                    message:@"You earned a top score! Enter your name:\n\n"
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    //alert.tag = kTag_EnterNameAlert;

    CGRect entryFieldRect = CGRectZero;
    if( UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation ) ) {
        entryFieldRect = CGRectMake(12, 90, 260, 25);
    }
    else {
        entryFieldRect = CGRectMake(12, 72, 260, 25);
    }
    textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:entryFieldRect];
    //textfield.tag = kTag_NameEmtryField;
    textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    textfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [alert addSubview:textfield];
    [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    [textfield release];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

# pragma -
# pragma alertView frame Methods

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSLog(@"name:%@   buttonID:%d",textfield.text,buttonIndex);
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self doAlertViewWithWebView];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@",alertView.message);
    }
}

// to set the alertView frame size.
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {

    [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 320)];
    for ( UIView *views in [alertView subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",views);
        if (views.tag == 1 || views.tag == 2) {
            [views setFrame:CGRectMake(views.frame.origin.x, views.frame.origin.y+200, views.frame.size.width, views.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
}

# pragma -
#pragma mark TableView Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 1) {
        return [_data count];
    }
    else
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* const SwitchCellID = @"SwitchCell";
    UITableViewCell* aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SwitchCellID];
    if( aCell == nil ) {
        aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SwitchCellID] autorelease];
        aCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Option %d", [indexPath row] + 1];
        aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        switchView.tag = [indexPath row]+1;
        aCell.accessoryView = switchView;
        [switchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
        [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(soundSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [switchView release];
    }

    return aCell;
}

- (void) soundSwitched:(UISwitch*) switchView {

    if (!switchView.on) {
        NSLog(@"chal bhag %d", switchView.tag);
    }
}

@end
```

Note: In your AppDelegate add as subView to this.