# UIAlertView maximum text length

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I just want to show some text on the `UIAlertView` but it is showing `"Null"` string if the text length larger than allowed size.

I am pretty sure the text will not larger than the screen (about a bit more than half), so I don't want to make it be complicated to implement a `ScrollView` for that.

I follow [problem in changing size of uialertview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975347/problem-in-changing-size-of-uialertview) to change the size of `AlertView`, but it does not work, additionally produce some weird visual effect.

I tried this third part component https://github.com/inamiy/YIPopupTextView, I can't even pass the compilation. (already import that 4 files into project.) I don't know why.

So, actually I just want to increase the size of text that allowed to show on `AlertView`. Any idea?

Comment: the text you want to show is like a paragraph?

Comment: make your own alert view its much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a tiny test program.  Here's the only thing I added to the Single View Application template:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSMutableString *message = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    while (message.length < 100000) {
        [message appendString:@"Hello, world!  "];
    }
    [message appendString:@"This is the end."];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

This works fine on the iPhone simulator running iOS 5.0, and on my iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.2.  All the text is displayed (in a scrollable text view).

Your problem is probably not with the size of the text.

Comment: Ya, that is my fault. Another mistake I made is I invoke UIAlertView in background thread, if the string length more than the screen, simulator will crash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange behavior while I was showing the result of a JSON object parsed in a dictionary and then printed on on an alertView (on Xcode 5.1.1, compiling for iOS 7.1 on iphone 64 bit simulator). For the same inputData:

```
[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"something" message:[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"json:%@",[inputData dictionaryRepresentation]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "withString:@""]substringToIndex:7035] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

correctly prints, but if I say "substringToIndex:7036" it shows only blank space...without "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:" method the limit is far beyond:

```
[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"something" message:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"json:%@",[inputData dictionaryRepresentation]] substringToIndex:13768] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

correctly prints, instead "substringToIndex:13769" not prints...I realize that is not a matter of maximum length but of special characters inside the JSON object