# How to change a UIAlertView's button background color?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uialertview

I've created `UIAlertView` with multiple buttons with the following code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
alert.tag = TAG_ALERT0;
alert.title = @"Notes";
alert.delegate = self;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Add Note"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Show Notes"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert show];
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a different background color to each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you ***can*** but **should not** modify the look of `UIAlertView` since Apple hates that shit.
Instead, create your own `UIView` that mimics the `alertView`.

Also... does the `initWithFrame` method even make a difference?
Example... Try:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

It won't make a difference.

So... I'd suggest:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notes"
                                                message:nil
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Add Note",@"Show Notes",nil];
[alert setTag:TAG_ALERT0];
[alert show];
```

---

But since you asked for sample code, the following example will be simple and to the point:

### STATUTORY WARNING:

1. Apple doesn't like this
2. Doesn't work in iOS7

Example:

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    UILabel *theTitle = [alertView valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
    [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    NSMutableArray *arrButtons = [alertView valueForKey:@"_buttons"];
    for (UIView *vwCurrent in arrButtons) {
        [vwCurrent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I want sample code of changing the button background color, could you help me with sample code?

Comment: @Eman87 : you can utilize `willPresentAlertView:` to modify parameters but it's not advisable. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3976993/2857130) but... this will only work in iOS6 since in iOS7 they have prevented such changes

Comment: @Eman87 : np :) but do look into making your own `alertView`. it's fun, easy and flexible. It's after all just a `UIView` with delegate/target-action callback